# Regex replace with positive lookahed with minimum length

Tags: c#, regex

I need regex matching word with at least one letter and at least one digit with minumum length 7 characters.

```
\b((?=.{7,15})[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z0-9]*-?\d?)\b
```

However in string 'MSW M19 6x14 4x100 ET38' it matches M19 which has only 3 characters.

Comment: If your string contains `ABC567-e4`, should it be returned? Maybe all you need is `s.Split().Where(x => x.Length >= 7 && x.Any(char.IsDigit) && x.Any(char.IsLetter))`?

Comment: Your lookahread matches any characters (`.`) including word boundaries. You need something like `\w{7,15}` instead. Still the rest of your regex doesn't match your description anyway.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/M5aWJy/3

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. Please also consider upvoting the answers that proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regex is really necessary, you may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\b(?=\w*\p{L})(?=\w*\d)\w{7,15}\b");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3D%5Cw*%5Cp%7BL%7D%29%28%3F%3D%5Cw*%5Cd%29%5Cw%7B7%2C15%7D%5Cb&i=MSW%20M19%206x14%204x100%20ET38%20ABC4567%20ABCDFERGE%205345643645%5C). Note if you only want to support ASCII uppercase letters and ASCII digits, replace `\w` with `[A-Z0-9]`, `\d` with `[0-9]` and `\p{L}` with `[A-Z]`.

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\w*\p{L})` - (or `(?=[0-9]*[A-Z])`) - a positive lookahead requiring at  least one letter after 0+ word chars (or after 0+ ASCII digits)
- `(?=\w*\d)`  - (or `(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])`) - a positive lookahead requiring at  least one diigt after 0+ word chars (or after 0+ ASCII uppercase ASCII letters)
- `\w{7,15}` - 7 to 15 word chars (note it includes `_`, you may use `[\w-[_]]{7,15}` to exclude it)
- `\b` - trailing (here) word boundary

Else, if you just have whitespace-separated chunks that you want to filter by length and presence of a letter and digit, use

```
var results = s.Split().Where(x => x.Length >= 7 && x.Any(char.IsDigit) && x.Any(char.IsLetter))
```

Answer (score 0):

`((?=.\w{6,})[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z0-9]*-?\d?)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you specifically need a positive lookahead, but this is a solution without using a lookahead.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]\w{6,}
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/mQIB9V/1